# How to know data is coming form partitioned filegroup or it is reading total records in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, partition

- I applied a partition on a DateTime column in a MSSQL table .
- Created Partition function, Scheme and 4 file groups and given boundary values.
- I have queried a result in this table with where condition on partitioned column.
- In this how-to know, the query is reading total records or related filegroup.
- How to know the query is using partition or not ?.

Answer (score 1):

One way is with the actual query execution plan. The Actual Partition Count of the seek/scan operator will show the actual number of partitions touched.

Another method is to run the query with `SET STATISTICS IO ON`, where the scan count of the table will reflect the number of partitions used.

Comment: In this we can see logical reads, physical reads, CPU time, elapsed time but I would like to know in which filegroup the query is read, no of pages read and no of records read.